# Generate SQLite DB from MySQL DB with data in .Net Core Web Api

Tags: mysql, sqlite, asp.net-core

How can I create a sqlite database with data from a mysql database with the .net core web api? I searched on the Internet, there are those who create a Sqlite database by changing the connectionString, but I need to get the data, and I need to regularly compare the data in mysql with the data in the sqlite file and update the sqlite file. How can I go about it? Do you have any resources or solutions that you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite) link. It about converting mysql to SQLite. Other than this you can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943577/asp-net-core-copying-data-from-sql-database-to-sqlite) link. Here you can get an idea to copy data from one db to another in the application.

Other than this you can also write a small utility to copy data from mysql and dump in sqllite.

And for the regular changings you can write a window service or an azure function (whatever is suitable) that will check for changings in mysql db and updates sqllite